# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError exception rather than a StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error

**Playing with Java (v9 specifically) I found this situation:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

interface A {
    static A staticMethod() {
        try {
            Method method = A.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0];
            return (A) method.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

That program flow should cause a StackOverflow error, however, I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 880
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 880
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 880
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

**According to Javadoc**

> ## Class NoClassDefFoundError
>
> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and **no definition of the class could be found**.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, **but the definition can no longer be found**.

### This is a weird error message, is it a bug?

**UPDATE:** *Bug Report Id: 9052375*

Executed from the command line and prints the expected error:
*The problem was, the exceptions used in `catch`*.

[image]

Comment: That *is* weird.  When printing `method`, it prints `public static A A.staticMethod()`, so the class definitely exists in the `ClassLoader`.

Comment: Since when can you add code to an interface? What happens if you write class instead of interface?

Comment: @maraca Since Java 8.

Comment: Java8, stackoverflow error it is :)

Comment: bug, should be reported IMHO

Comment: @Eugene I will, I also think it’s a bug.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique because of your method all time call himself. just call other method

Comment: @SeniorPomidor I know that, I was playing with Java and I found that situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug and it also has nothing to do with static methods in interfaces.

The `java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED` message is also not relevant and is just an artifact of running the code from IDE. Running the same class from the command line will result in `Exception in thread "main"` only.

Lets simplify your example to

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        recursive();
    }

    public static void recursive() throws Exception {
        try {
            Test.class
                    .getDeclaredMethod( "recursive" )
                    .invoke( null );
        } catch ( InvocationTargetException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on:

- The recursive method causes `StackOverflowError`, as expected.
- The `StackOverflowError` is wrapped into `InvocationTargetException` which is thrown from the deepest nested call to `method.invoke()`.
- The `InvocationTargetException` is immediately caught and JVM tries to execute `printStackTrace()` but in order to do that it needs to load some classes. But remember that at this point the stack is depleted and any non-trivial methods will hit `StackOverflowError` again, which is exactly what happens somewhere inside the class loader when it tries to load some class required to print a stack trace. The class loader did found the class, but failed to load and initialize it, and it reports that as `NoClassDefFoundError`.

The following code will prove that `InvocationTargetException` indeed wraps `StackOverflowError`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        recursive();
    }

    public static void recursive() throws Exception {
        try {
            Test.class
                    .getDeclaredMethod( "recursive" )
                    .invoke( null );
        } catch ( InvocationTargetException e ) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println(e.getTargetException());
        }
    }
}
```

And the following code will prove that if classes required to execute `printStackTrace()` are already loaded, then the code behaves as expected (prints a stack trace for `InvocationTargetException` caused by `StackOverflowError`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        new Exception().printStackTrace(); // initialize all required classes
        recursive();
    }

    public static void recursive() throws Exception {
        try {
            Test.class
                    .getDeclaredMethod( "recursive" )
                    .invoke( null );
        } catch ( InvocationTargetException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The open question is why reflection API handles`StackOverflowError` at all, instead of simply terminating the whole call chain with the error.